# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.myapp' In Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-errors

`File "C:\Users\user\app-rest\app\app\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.myapp.views import UserViewSet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.myapp'`

Not sure what the issue is but when I comment out the import and the related views on my URL page, it works. Could it be from the folder being app\app\url being the same name twice? if it is how can I change that without screwing up the rest of my code?

settings are set up right because it usually works.

Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: probably it could be `from myapp.views import UserViewSet`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use case for a relative import, if you are accessing the view from within the same `django app`, then replace the import statement with

`from .views import UserViewSet`

[Reference](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-imports)